# Integration of SolrJ with Spring Batch

Tags: java, solr, spring-batch, solrj

I am using Spring Batch.Following is the jobContext.xml file, `JdbcCursorItemReader` is reading data from MySQL Database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>

    <import resource="infrastructureContext.xml"/>

    <batch:job id="readProcessWriteProducts">
        <batch:step id="readWriteProducts">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="reader" processor="processer" writer="writer"  commit-interval="5"> </chunk>
            </tasklet>          
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>  

    <bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="sql" value="SELECT id, name, description, price FROM product"></property>
        <property name="rowMapper" ref="productItemReader"></property>      
    </bean>

    <bean id="productItemReader" class="com.itl.readprocesswrite.reader.ProductItemReader"></bean>

    <bean id="processer" class="com.itl.readprocesswrite.processor.ProductItemProcessor">
        <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="writer" class="com.itl.readprocesswrite.writer.ProductJdbcItemWriter">
        <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Now, I want to read data from Apache Solr.
I tried following code to read data from Apache Solr.

```
public class SolrJDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException {
         System.out.println("SolrJDrive::main");
         SolrServer solr = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
         ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
         params.set("qt", "/select");
         params.set("q", "*:*");
         params.set("spellcheck", "on");
         params.set("spellcheck.build", "true");
         QueryResponse response = solr.query(params);
         SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
         for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
           System.out.println(results.get(i));
         }
    }//end of method main
}//end of class SolrJDrive
```

Now how do I integrate this with Spring Batch?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what I said on your other question ([Is it possible to integrate Apache Solr with Spring Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931814/is-it-possible-to-integrate-apache-solr-with-spring-batch)), here's an example of your Solr custom ItemReader :

```
public class SolrReader implements ItemReader<SolrDocumentList> {

    @Override
    public SolrDocumentList read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {


        SolrServer solr = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
        ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
        params.set("qt", "/select");
        params.set("q", "*:*");
        params.set("spellcheck", "on");
        params.set("spellcheck.build", "true");
        QueryResponse response = solr.query(params);
        SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();

        return results;
    }
}
```

You would then need an ItemProcessor to convert your `SolrDocumentList` to something you can work with (ie. a POJO).